# Segment customers by coupon code used on checkout & automatically update MailChimp list

Tags: onepage-checkout, email, coupon, transactional, customer-segmentation

We'd like to automatically populate MailChimp lists based on the coupon code new subscribers enter at checkout.

Currently, through MageMonkey, subscribers are automatically added to a master email list in MailChimp. We would like to add them to this list AND to another list based on the coupon code they enter. New subscribers who use a coupon code on checkout would therefore be added to two lists automatically.

I doubt this is part of the core functionality of Magento, but is anyone aware of an extension that will do this?